# Why is removing filter for individual columns more performant compared to removing filter from entire table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm writing dax to change the context using CALCULATE.

I'm observing that:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[saleamt], ALL(Product), Product[name]='test')
```

The above is slower compared to:

```
CALCULATE(SUM(FactSales[saleamt], ALL(Product[name]), Product[name]='test')
```

Effectively both filter the expanded table so what makes 2nd DAX faster?

Answer (score 1):

This is because All(Product) returns all rows. And All(Product[Name]) returns all unique product names.

> The following remarks are valid using ALL as a table expression:
>
> - Using a table argument, ALL returns all the rows of the table
>   including any duplicated rows.
> - Using a single column argument, ALL returns all the unique values of the column.
> - Using two or more columns arguments, ALL returns all the unique combinations of values in multiple columns.
>
> In every case, ALL includes in the result the additional blank row
> generated for invalid relationships.

https://dax.guide/all/

Comment: Is this in any way related to table expansion?

Comment: And does the behaviour change if I use REMOVEFILTERS instead of ALL?